# Will spawning a python script twice from NodeJS mess with the stdout.flush returned values?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have a route on my NodeJS server which will spawn a python script like so:

```
const pythonProcess = spawn("python3",["/var/www/ip/uploads/script.py", project_num])
```

I then listen for a stdout flush like so:

```
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {

})
```

If the route is called by 2 different clients at roughly the same time, will they interfere with each other? I have seen some cases of the 2 clients getting the same data returned by stdout, when it should have been different. This might be caused by my python script, but I also have a hunch that getting data from stdout can be a bit shoddy.

Comment: Why would they? You spawn 2 different processes with 2 different stdouts, there are NO  shared resources.

Comment: @deathangel908 I have no idea. I just suspect it's the case because the data being returned for one client, looks exactly like the data returned for the next client, even though it should have been different.

Comment: Just run this script from a terminal you would get the same result, `your_script.py  > a.txt & your_script.py > b.txt`. It's not related to node.